# How to enable all actuator endpoints in spring boot bootstrap properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

This project is spring boot cloud config client project.I tried varies option that is used in application.properties but none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: you could add the line blow to your `applicatin.properties` to expose all endpoints that are enable by default.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

most of endpoints are enabled by default but not all of them are exposed.

have a look at this part of [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints) about enabling&exposing actuator endpoints